# useState not showing updated value in useEffect in React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, intersection-observer

I have a useState

`const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);`

then I have a function where on click it sets the setStarted to true

`setStarted(true)`

then I have a useEffect and in there I have an IntersectionObserver that calls a function and function has a forEach and in there I am checking for started but it is always false. I am doing console log which is showing false and also the functionality isn't working so I am sure it is false.

```
let options = {
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: [0.5, 0.5]
    };

useEffect(() => {
  let handleStart = (entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (started) {
        //do something
      } 
      console.log("started value " + started);
    });
  };
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleStart, options);

  observer.observe(currentRef.current);
}, []);
```

Comment: Did you try to add `started` as a dependency to `useEffect`?

Comment: ```useEffect((started) => {``` like this? i tried that

Comment: In your code you have passed empty array as dependency to useEffect, which means it will only run once during mount process. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021462/4149453 - It will run everyting value of `started ` changes

Comment: @user3253146 no like the one below suggested by Jeroen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `started` as a dependency for `useEffect`. It should be as follow:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (started) {
      // Do something with started
    }
}, [started])
```

When you have an empty dependency array, the `useEffect` will only run when the page initially loads (mounts).